# how to combine background image AND css gradient?

Tags: css, background, gradient

I've searched around for over an hour without finding the correct answer before posting this, so hopefully someone can assist me. I have a div with a big image on my mainpage that is rendered like this:

```
<div id="hero"></div>
```

It works perfectly right now, but I want to add a gradient to the left and right side of the image to fade it out into almost black, however I can't seem to get it working.

The CSS for the hero div is:

```
#hero{
background-image: url("hero.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
width:100%;
height:200px;
position:relative;
}
```

What I am trying to add is:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(38, 35, 31, 0.8) 0%, rgba(65, 60, 53, 0) 50%, rgba(38, 35, 31, 0.8) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
bottom: 0;
content: "";
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
right: 0;
top: 0;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
```

However when adding it to the div, it's not working. I even tried combining the background-image and the gradient like:

```
background-image: url("hero.jpg"), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(38, 35, 31, 0.8) 0%, rgba(65, 60, 53, 0) 50%, rgba(38, 35, 31, 0.8) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but that's just showing a white space.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for any hints :)

EDIT: Note that I also have some content (buttons and text) inside the "hero" div, so it should not overlay the content, only the background image.

Comment: Why not fix the image - works all the time

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just found my own answer, so I am posting it here in case anyone else needs it!

The way to fix it was use:

```
#hero:before
```

for the background gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you place the background materials in the wrong order, to use multiple background feature, you should remember that the first placed background material (image or gradient) will cover the after placed backgrounds.
Secondly, your colors can distinguish the gradient background against a white background **but** it's fairly dim against an image background. So I've tried changing it to `black`. Here are code details:

```
#hero{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, rgba(38, 35, 31, .5) 40%, rgba(65, 60, 53, 0) 50%, rgba(38, 35, 31, .5) 60%, black), 
              url("http://placekitten.com/500/200");
  ...
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TLSAh/)